# プロキシ環境下でのSymfonyのインストールについて

Tags: php, symfony2

プロキシ環境下でSymfony Installerをダウンロードしようとすると通信エラーが発生しダウンローロードができません。
ブラウザでアクセスするとsymfony.pharがダウンロードできるのでphpがプロキシの使用を認識していないのだと思い、環境変数を設定しましたがうまくいきません。
php にプロキシを認識させる方法をご教授願えないでしょうか。

環境
Windows7 SP1 x86
php Ver5.6.21
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyserver:ports/
set HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=1

実行コマンド
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('http://symfony.com/installer'));"

エラーメッセージ
Warning: file_get_contents(......): failed to open stream:
 接続済みの呼び出し先が一定の時間を過ぎても正しく応答しなかったため、接続できま
せんでした。または接続済みのホストが応答しなかったため、確立された接続は失敗しま
した。
 in Command line code on line 1

以上よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Symfonyのインストールに関していえば、単にダウンロードできればいいのでブラウザでダウンロードしてもいい気はします。。

Answer (score 1):

↓contextを作成して引数に指定すればプロキシ経由できるようです。
 ワンライナーでは難しいかもしれませんね。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.stream-context-create.php#111032

cURLを使用するのではだめなのでしょうか？
curl -L "http://symfony.com/installer" > symfony.phar

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
プラットフォームが Windows のため cURL を使用するためには、このコマンドを別途インストールしなければならないので…。
ご指摘頂いた通り context でプロキシ情報を作成し引数していすることで解決させました。
実行コマンドは Symfony の公式サイトで指定しているダウンロード方法ですので、せめて注意書きでプロキシ環境化ではうまくいかないと書いてあるとうれしいですよね。